# AlertDialog inside of AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I am programming an Android project, in which I have an AlertDialog which pops up on click of an ImageButton. In the AlertDialog, I have a few options (clickable), and one of them is "Custom". When clicking on it, another AlertDialog pops up, and inside of it there's an EditText controller. You input a number and click on "Finish" (PositiveButton). After the click on finish, the app checks if the number is alright, and if it is alright, a function to add this number to some total happens and a progressbar changes for the positive side.

My bug is that when I click on Finish (with a proper number and everything), I should press the image and the "custom" button again in order for anything happen (in the calculation and the progress bar).

Here's my code:

```
public void handleDrinking(View v)
    {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"A cup of water (240ml)", "A small bottle of water (500ml)", "A bottle of 1.5 liters of water", "A bottle of 2 liters of water", "Custom"};
        customWaterDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        addWater = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        final EditText plzAmount = new EditText(this);
        addWater.setTitle("Choose your size of water");
        addWater.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                int x=0;
                if (which == 0)
                {
                    x = 240;
                }
                else if (which == 1)
                {
                    x=500;
                }
                else if (which == 2)
                {
                    x=1500;
                }
                else if (which == 3)
                {
                    x=2000;
                }
                else if (which == 4)
                {
                    plzAmount.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                    layout.addView(plzAmount);
                    customWaterDialog.setView(layout);
                    customWaterDialog.setTitle("Please enter the amount of water you have drank");
                    customWaterDialog.setPositiveButton("Finish", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            String data = plzAmount.getText().toString();
                            if (!data.equals("")) {
                                customAmountWater = Integer.valueOf(data);
                            } else {
                                customAmountWater = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    customWaterDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                    customWaterDialog.show();
                    x=customAmountWater;

                }
                me.drankWater(x);
                me.setWaterDrankToday(x);
                handleScreen();
            }
        });
        addWater.show();
    }
```

What should I do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I couldn't understand your bug. You mean that when you press finish button the first dialog still remains there?

Comment: No @FarooqArshed. What I meant is the function that was supposed to happen when I pressed the PositiveButton happened only when I pressed the button again.

Comment: Still not clear. please paste handleScreen(); code. It will give more idea.

Comment: @FarooqArshed

Sorry for pastebin link, too long to post directly
http://pastebin.com/mH27H9J1

Comment: You should call me.drankWater(x);
                me.setWaterDrankToday(x);
                handleScreen();

inside OnClickListener of customWaterDialog as well. And also assign x inside onclick listener. Not outside.

Comment: @FarooqArshed Nope, still the same